# How to use set the position of a body directly in Box2D Libgdx?

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to call the setPosition function in the body but it doesn't seem to work, what do I need to do to make it work correctly?

These are the classes used

```
class Box2DModel {
    private val gravity: Vector2
    val world: World
    private var accumulator = 0f
    private lateinit var worldBounds: Rectangle
    private var isPaused = false

    companion object {
        const val GRAVITY_FORCE_Y = 0f
        const val GRAVITY_FORCE_X = 0f
    }

    init {
        Box2D.init()
        gravity = Vector2(GRAVITY_FORCE_X, GRAVITY_FORCE_Y)
        world = World(gravity, true)
    }


    fun disposeSafely() {
        world.disposeSafely()
    }

    fun stepWorldBox2d() {
        if (!isPaused) {
            val deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.deltaTime
            accumulator += deltaTime.coerceAtMost(0.25f)
            if (accumulator >= GameConstant.Physical.STEP_TIME) {
                accumulator -= GameConstant.Physical.STEP_TIME
                world.step(
                    GameConstant.Physical.STEP_TIME,
                    GameConstant.Physical.VELOCITY_ITERATIONS,
                    GameConstant.Physical.POSITION_ITERATIONS
                )
            }
        }
    }

    fun createWorldBounds(tiledMap: TiledMap) {
        val w = (
            tiledMap.properties.get("width").toString().toFloat()
                * tiledMap.properties.get("tilewidth")
                .toString()
                .toFloat()) / GameConstant.ConvertUnits.PPM
        val h = (tiledMap.properties.get("height").toString().toFloat()
            * tiledMap.properties.get("tileheight")
            .toString()
            .toFloat()) / GameConstant.ConvertUnits.PPM
        worldBounds = Rectangle(0f, 0f, w, h)
    }
}


Parent class where I created the actor

abstract class AbstractActor(x: Float, y: Float, world: World) : Group() {
    var body: Body? = null
    val velocity = Vector2(0f, 0f)

    var frame: TextureRegion? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                field = Scene2DSkin.defaultSkin.atlas.findRegion("white")
            }
            return field
        }
        set(textureRegion) {
            if (textureRegion != null) {
                val texture = textureRegion.texture
                val w = toBox2DUnits(texture.width)
                val h = toBox2DUnits(texture.height)
                this.setSize(w, h)
                field = textureRegion
            }
        }



    override fun rotationChanged() {
        val angle = (rotation * (Math.PI / 180)).toFloat()
        body?.setTransform(body?.worldCenter, angle)
    }

    override fun sizeChanged() {
        originX = half(width)
        originY = half(height)
    }

    override fun positionChanged() {

    }

    private fun half(value: Float): Float {
        return value * 0.5f
    }


    fun randomColor(): Color {
        fun rRGB(): Float {
            return Random.nextInt(0, 100) / 100f
        }
        return Color(rRGB(), rRGB(), rRGB(), 1f)
    }


    override fun draw(batch: Batch, parentAlpha: Float) {
        if (frame != null) {
            batch.setColor(color.r, color.b, color.g, color.a)
            batch.draw(frame, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation)
        }
    }
}

And finally this one where I try to define the position in the Act method


class PlayerActor(x: Float, y: Float, world: World) : AbstractActor(x, y, world) {
    init {
        setPosition(x, y)
        setSize(2f, 1f)
    }

    init {
        val myBodyDef = BodyDef().apply {
            type = DynamicBody
            position.set(x + originX, y + originY)
            angle = 0f
        }
        body = world.createBody(myBodyDef)


        val polygonShape = PolygonShape()
        polygonShape.setAsBox(originX, originY)

        val fixtureDef = FixtureDef()
        fixtureDef.apply {
            shape = polygonShape
            density = 1f
        }

        body?.createFixture(fixtureDef)
        polygonShape.disposeSafely()

    }
    
    override fun act(delta: Float) {
        super.act(delta)
        body?.position?.x = 0f
        println(body?.position?.x)

    }
```

When I use setLinearVelocity it works perfectly, if anyone can help me I would be very grateful, or if someone knows an easier way to synchronize the position of the body with the position of the image it would be very useful.

Comment: positionChanged() meant to be empty?

Comment: yes, I didn't implement anything in it because it's the actor's position, not the body's, I managed to solve my problem and found that apparently setPosition only defines the initial position